# iOS 8.2 MonitoringForRegion delegate Method was working perfectly and now not getting called

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, clregion

Since yesterday, I have a problem with monitoring region working with CLLocationManager

PS: my project was working perfectly I'm testing it everyday, but today this delegate method was called after 1 minute of entering a region

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{}
```

and now it's no more getting called I have made another project only with CLLocationManager for testing the delegate method and the same thing is happening.

Can you just tell me what the hell this could be?

[UPDATE]

i found this [helpful link about iOS Region Monitoring after iPhone Restart](http://blog.twocanoes.com/post/33838454722/ios-region-monitoring-after-iphone-restart)

Comment: May be the answer will come from heaven!

Comment: :( no but seriously this will gonna make me crazy ! i'm spending hour on it and nothing !! wha't going on with CLLocation or with my phone

Comment: Just check ! whether  the WIFI signal in your phone is strong.

Comment: i'm checking the WIFI signal but it seems like everything is ok, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just check that below service is on or off.

> [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] returns YES
>   CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions contains valid regions

Apple document specified that events make take between 3-5 minutes to fire.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you but [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] returns YES is DEPRECATED in ios 7 and my monitoredRegions was correct ..

Answer (score 0):

Does *locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:* get called?

Do you call *requestStateForRegion:* after *startMonitoringForRegion:*?

Is this in background or foreground?